# How to draw plot of comparing normal and binomial distribution R?

Tags: r

I have to draw such type of plot but I can't understand how to do it. I have to plots of these functions. Normal:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(x)/sum(abs(x)))/2.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density"))
```

and binomial:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(10)
tibble(x = sort(rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 90)+
  geom_density(color = "red")
```

and I can't understand how to make comparing of two of these functions on one plot in range [0,1]. Maybe I have to change my plots. But anyway I can't got how to add two plots at the certain range. Maybe someone know how to do it?

Comment: `range(sort(rbinom(1e5, 1e5, 0.001)))  # 61 146` is not in the range [0,1] though. You're question is thus unclear to me at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to get out of such comparison. Before putting the two graphs together, I think your code may have some issues: 1) your `cumsum(abs(x)/sum(abs(x)))` may not be correct, I replaced it with `cumsum(abs(10-x)/sum(abs(10-x)))`. 
Second, for binomial distribution, `rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001)` will give you numbers not probabilities, I replaced it with `rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001)/1e5`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1<-tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(10-x)/sum(abs(10-x)))/2.5)
df2<-tibble(x1 = sort(rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001)/1e5)) 

  ggplot(df1, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density")) + 
    geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(x = x1, y = ..density..), bins = 90)
```

This will produce: 
[image]

You can change `bins` to adjust height. However, we need to be careful with the  interpretation of the difference between two distributions: one is the distribution of individuals with mean = 0 and SD =1 (normal distribution) while the other is the distribution of population estimates with a probability of 0.001 and sample size of 1e5.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), fill="red", bins = 15)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density")) +  
  geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(x = x1, y = ..density..), color = "green", fill="green", bins = 15)
```

[image]

Comment: in general it looks really good, but can we scale it more if it is possible?

Comment: Not sure about that. You only have used up both y axis labels, no place to add one more.

Comment: It seems that I said smth incorrect :) Can we make this big vertical line smaller? And scale more or hist and plot lines if it is possible?

Comment: Possible. I am not with my computer at moment but will give a try later.

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: can you please look on my another question which is connected with your answer, I can't understand some points https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355299/how-i-can-understand-code-of-two-distributions-r ?

Answer (score 0):

You could save your data and just add the new geom_ with new data and a new x variable to your plot with using ggplot() again. Then, your plot will be added to the previous plot.
However, the xlim (range) seems to be too small.

Silke

```
data1 <- tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
                 cumulative = cumsum(abs(x)/sum(abs(x)))/2.5)

                set.seed(10)
data2 <-          tibble(x = sort(rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001))) 

ggplot(data = data1, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density")) +
  geom_histogram(data = data2,aes(x = x,y = ..density..), bins = 90)+
  geom_density(color = "green") + xlim(0,1)
```