# How I can understand code of two distributions R?

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
df1<-tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(10-x)/sum(abs(10-x)))/2.5)
df2<-tibble(x1 = sort(rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001)/1e5))
```

which was posted in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58298622/how-to-draw-plot-of-comparing-normal-and-binomial-distribution-r). After some research I still can't understand several things and I will be so pleased if someone will explain it for me:

1. Which params we have at `df1` distribution?
2. Which params we have at `df2` distribution? Why we have to divide on 1e5 and on which formula it is based?
3. Why we have to use 10 at such scope - `(10-x)` and 2.5 also.

I will be happy if someone explain this questions for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your previous question is wrong and misleading, although, to be fair, you did not ask the question very clearly.

I think what you are perhaps trying to do is compare the binomial distribution to the Normal approximation to it. The binomial is the number of successes you get if you do something N times, and the chance of each being a success is p.  The mean of this is Np, and the standard deviation is sqrt(Np(1-p)), which can be used to approximate it with a Normal distribution.

One way to compare them using `ggplot` would be like this...

```
library(tidyverse)

trials <- 100   #i.e. N in the explanation above
prob <- 0.1     #i.e. p in the explanation above
sims <- 100000  #the number of simulations you want (1e5 in your previous question)

df <- tibble(n = 1:sims,
             normal = sort(rnorm(sims,                               #no of variates
                                 trials * prob,                      #mean
                                 sqrt(trials * prob * (1-prob)))),   #standard deviation
             binomial = sort(rbinom(sims, 
                                    trials, 
                                    prob)))
```

Then, to compare the (discrete) histogram of the binomial distribution (in red) with the (continuous) density of the Normal approximation (in blue), you can do

```
df %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(x = normal), 
               alpha = 0.5, 
               fill = "blue") +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = binomial, 
                     y = stat(density)), #normalises scale to sum to 1 
                 alpha = 0.5, 
                 fill = "red", 
                 binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

And to compare the cumulative distributions (taking advantage of the fact that we have sorted the variates in our dataframe)...

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(y = n/sims)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = normal), 
            colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x = binomial), 
            colour = "red")
```

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for so great answer, but can you explain please - is df the sum of two distributions?

Comment: `df` includes both distributions in separate columns - it makes the plotting easier if they are in the same data frame.

Comment: hmmm.... I'm trying to compare with the previous answer and plot, and I can't see two functions)) I understood that I have drawn two distributions but I can't recognise where they are))

Comment: There are two plots - one for the density/histogram, the other for the cumulative density/histogram (I've added them to the answer above).  In each, the binomial is in red and the normal is blue.  It doesn't correspond exactly to the previous answer - I was just trying to show you an approach that you can use to compare the two distributions, once you have clarified exactly what you are trying to compare.

Comment: but in general I still don't get any answer on my first questions :( thank you for your help